# how to dump the mongodb collection which has sensitive information using command

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

i am using mongo db and it has 10 collections and from them one of the collection (system.users) has sensitive information like this

**db.system.users.find()**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6572c3c6a9f24c464097225a"), "user" : "admin", "pwd" : "password", "roles" : [ "readWrite", "databaseName" ], "_class" : "com.package.MongoDbConfig$UserCredentials" }
```

when i am trying to take the mongodump i am getting getting 9 collections only and unable to get the system.users collection.

**command**

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db database -u admin-p password --out /path
```

and i tried to run the with credentials also bet getting this issue

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db database --out /path
```

**Error:**

```
Failed: can't create session: failed to connect to mongodb://localhost:27017/: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed
```

Note: I don't have any password-based authentication to mongo db, it will be directly access

please help me

Thanks

Comment: What is the database name? Why do you consider the data as sensitive information? Do you store the password as clear text?

Comment: You write "I don't have any password-based authentication to MongoDB" - but why are you then providing username/password in your command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db database --collection system.users --out /path

Answer (score 0):

Is your users collection in your database or it is a separate collection in different database?

If in same database and If you are connected to your mongodb server,Try this in terminal.

```
mongodump --db yourDbName --authenticationDatabase yourAuthDb(eg:admin) --username yourUserName --password yourPassword --out /pathToDump
```

Comment: i have only one database bro and i tried your suggestion
mongodump --db tempDb --authenticationDatabase tempDb --username user --password admin123 --out /root/dir

 but getting like this
 Failed: can't create session: failed to connect to mongodb://localhost/: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.

Comment: Can you please check the status of mongodb server.
Is it in running(active) state?

Comment: yes brother it is running i am able to connect to mongo terminal also by using mongo command

Comment: and one more this my mongo don't have any credentials i mean it will connect automatically but collection have sensitive information so how to get that

Comment: The MongoDB server is running, otherwise you could not get any error message from it.

Comment: The Mongo DB server is running fine but i have doubt about the collection name system.users is there a naming restriction for the MongoDB collection

Comment: Database names cannot be empty and must have fewer than 64 characters. Collection names should begin with an underscore or a letter character, and cannot: contain the $ . be an empty string (e.g. "" )

Comment: so my issue is with dot right?

Comment: I think so.try renaming collection into simple name and take a dump again.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: Collection namse starting with `system.` will be treated as system collections. Unless you are using an extremely old version of MongoDB, only the `system.users` collection in the admin database is used for authentication/authorization

Comment: @AjajAli like you said problem is with system. bro. thanks